# android studio emulator process exit with code 1 linux mint

Tags: android, android-emulator

[image]I am having issue with android emulator and it is not starting the device. i am using linux mint. this error is shown

```
5:49 PM Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Unknown AVD name [Pixel_2_API_29], use -list-avds to see valid list.

5:49 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

i dont know how to list avds .

i was able to run it from the command by using

> sudo ./emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_29_x86 -use-system-libs

BUT not working in avd managers window.

Comment: Have you granted ownership of kvm to user? if not run command: sudo chown $USER /dev/kvm

Answer (score 0):

Please run following commands step by step..

```
1.adb kill-server (To kil adb server)
2.adb start-server (To start adb server)
3.adb devices (To list avds)
```

Comment: Please click on Invalidate caches/Restart from Android Studio

Comment: did that also . still the  same issue , added image